# How to create miultiple rows from a single row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to come up with a program that creates multiple rows and columns for each row based on a value in a column.

Here's a look at my data

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("test data.xlsx")
```

| Id | #ofweeks | Manhours | StartDate | EndDate | Startingyear | StartingWeek |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 2 | 10 | 1/15/2023 | 1/29/2023 | 2023 | 3 |
| bbb | 3 | 12 | 2/12/2023 | 3/05/2023 | 2023 | 7 |

The table needs to be expanded so that every row is expanded by the number of weeks.
There needs to be columns added for the Labor hours per week and columns which count the number of weeks for each Id.

The results should look like this

| Id | #ofweeks | Manhours | StartDate | EndDate | Startingyear | StartingWeek | WeekCount | Year | Week# |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 2 | 10 | 1/15/2023 | 1/29/2023 | 2023 | 3 | 1 | 2023 | 3 |
| aaa | 2 | 10 | 1/15/2023 | 1/29/2023 | 2023 | 3 | 2 | 2023 | 4 |
| bbb | 3 | 12 | 2/12/2023 | 3/05/2023 | 2023 | 7 | 1 | 2023 | 7 |
| bbb | 3 | 12 | 2/12/2023 | 3/05/2023 | 2023 | 7 | 2 | 2023 | 8 |
| bbb | 3 | 12 | 2/12/2023 | 3/05/2023 | 2023 | 7 | 3 | 2023 | 10 |

I've been able to get the table in the format I needed. However there's one more issue.

I've added the following columns

```
# Add column for number of week for each expanded job record row
df['Week Count'] = df.groupby(['Id']).cumcount() + 1 

# Add column for year for each job record row
from math import floor
df['Year'] = np.where((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1) > 52,
                   df['Starting Year'] + floor((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count'])/52),
                   df['Starting Year'])

# Add column for the number of week for the calendar year for each job record row
df['Week #'] = np.where((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1) > 52,
                   (df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-53),
                    df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1)

# Add leading 0 to the Week # Column
df['Week #'] = df['Week #'].astype(str).str.pad(2, side = 'left', fillchar = '0')

# Add a column Period which concatenates the Year and Week #  columns 
df['Period'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + "-" + df['Week  #'].astype(str)
```

However, This is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 7
      4 # Add column for year for each job record row
      5 from math import floor
      6 df['Year'] = np.where((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1) > 52,
----> 7                        df['Starting Year'] + floor((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count'])/52), 
      8                        df['Starting Year'])
     10 # Add column for the number of week for the calendar year for each job record row
     11 df['Week #'] = np.where((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1) > 52,
     12                        (df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-53),
     13                         df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:191, in _coerce_method.<locals>.wrapper(self)
    189 if len(self) == 1:
    190     return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 191 raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have expended the dataframe, I would add the columns such as:

```
df['WeekCount'] = df.groupby('Id')['Id'].cumcount() + 1
```

To account for activities that go past a calendar year you can try:

```
df['Week#'] = np.where((df['StartingWeek'] + df['WeekCount']-1) > 52,
                       (df['StartingWeek'] + df['WeekCount']-53),
                        df['StartingWeek'] + df['WeekCount']-1)
```

To add a "current year" (based on Edit) you can try:

```
from math import floor
df['CurrentYear'] = np.where((df['StartingWeek'] + df['WeekCount']-1) > 52,
                       df['Startingyear'] + floor((df['StartingWeek'] + df['WeekCount'])/52),
                       df['Startingyear'])
```

Comment: I had another question. If I wanted to add a Column Year which just lists the year the current week is in. For a Week # that goes into the next Calendar Year and the counter restarts at 1 the Year would be the current year +1.

Comment: Figured it out! I used the following:



df['Year'] = np.where((df['Starting Week period'] + df['Week Count']-1) > 52,
                       (df['Starting Year'] + 1),
                        df['Starting Year'])

Comment: This will work only if it's one year, not if it goes past two years. In my edited answer I'm dividing by the number of weeks per year and then summing it. So if it's less than 52, it's the one, if it exceeds between 53 and 103, it'll add 1, if it's 104 or higher it will add 2 years, and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the help! You're right this won't work when it goes past 2 years as I've found in my data. I tried implementing what you suggested, but I'm getting the following error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: I've edited my Question to reflect my new issue. I was wondering if the Week # Column would also reset properly if it continues past 2 years?